# an error happened while creating graph: path storage/emulated/0/graphhopper/maps/mapfile doesnot exist

Tags: android, openstreetmap, graphhopper

i was using graphhopper android example(from github) in my project. it was working fine but tomorrow it started giving error about path of maps stored on device. my whole project is stuck because of this. Is it because of some recent changes in repository? please help [here is the image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU1hC.jpg)

Comment: Did this file exist previously? Why doesn't it exist any more? Is it located somewhere else?

Comment: yes file exists in the same directory as before.. you can see in the image that maps loads but then it gives error about file path and routing does not works..

Answer (score 0):

This was a temporary bug only occurred for the master branch which is now fixed: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/704

For future requests: please include the OS, java and GH version and prefer stable versions and be a bit more descriptive with logs etc :)